# Provide assistance with writing a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm in a group project, and was tasked with adding a constructor to an already existing program. Problem is, I'm not sure what my group-mate is asking. Below is a screenshot from the chat -

[image: showing image]

I'm supposed to make a constructor within this:

```
public class UserMenu extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private String a = "";
    private UserInfo user;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UserMenu frame = new UserMenu(testUser.tes(testUser.tUser));
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

While referencing the "UserInfo" from this (separate java file):

```
public class UserInfo {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private double Checkings = 0.0;
    private double Savings = 0.0;
    private boolean hasCheckings = false;
    private boolean hasSaving = false;
    public Loan loan;

    public UserInfo(String firstname, String lastname, String username, String password, String email) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for you to ask your mate directly? I personally never heard "constructor as an attribute" phrase - no idea what that could mean - attribute is one thing, constructor is something totally different.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

### What is a Constructor:

> Constructor is a block of code that initializes the newly created object. A constructor resembles an instance method in java but it’s not a method as it doesn’t have a return type. In short constructor and method are different. People often refer constructor as special type of method in Java.

Constructor has same name as the class and looks like this in a java code.

```java
public class MyClass{
   //This is the constructor
   MyClass(){
   }
   ..
}
```

### Your Case:

in your case the constructor will look like:

```
public class UserMenu extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private String a = "";
    private UserInfo user;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public UserMenu(JPanel contentPane, String a, UserInfo user){

        this.contentPane = contentPane;
        this.a = a;
        this.user = user;
    }

[...] //rest of the code
```

if you want to learn more about it you can see [Constructors in Java](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/)